# HIbernate Many to Many with self entity Using annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-annotations

I have a problem in Hibernate Many to Many relationships.

I have one table called `Projects` that contains the following fields:

> (Project id,Project Title,Created Date,Project Manager)

I also populate a field called `team` for project(Multiple select Combobox),  which associates multiple project members.

So when I save projects data into the `Projects` Table using Hibernate I want another table called `Project_team` to be generated.  It should contain the following fields:

> (project_id, team_member_id)

So for example if I enter data like (Project Title="ERP",Created Date="16/2/1013" ,Project Manager="XYZ") I should have another table project_team (project_id=1, team_member_id=1).

Would it be self Many to Many relationship  or else? Should I make another bean for Team_member and then I will have to perform many to many ?

Comment: What does the table look like that holds the teams?  Can a person be part of more than one team? Could you provide a little more information on your data model?

Comment: Table that holds the team members wud be project_participants (project_id,participants_id) for example **project_id** 1,1 then **participants_id** could be 2,3 so team(users 2 & 3) will be for project (with id 1) . Now You got? Sorry I am not asking question with correct format.

Comment: How does a participant get associated with a team?  What I'm after is the structure of this team table because it changes how things should be mapped.  If a participant has one team will be mapped differently than if a participant has 1..n teams.  Does particpants_id = team_member_id?

Comment: I am directly entering participant_ids. You don't need to consider TEAM.

Comment: yes participants_id=team_member_id.

Comment: I posted a solution, I'm not sure if I understand your data model 100%.  If you need more help let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a junction table to handle the many-to-many association between a `Team` and a `Project`, however you would not need a bean or class for this junction table.  The following example would create a uni-directional association between `PROJECT` and `PARTICIPANT`.  You will need to create a `TEAM_MEMBER` or `PARTICIPANT` table in order to perform this association.

**Projects.java**

```
public class Project{

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, targetEntity = Participant.class)
@JoinTable(name = "PROJECT_TEAM", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_MEMBER_ID", referencedColumnName = "PROJECT_ID") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PARTICIPANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARTICIPANT_ID") })

    private List<Participant> team = new ArrayList<Participant>();

    //Accessors - get/setTeam method
}
```

This answer assumes the following data model is in place:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT(
   PROJECT_ID int,
   PROJECT_TITLE varchar(50),
   CREATED_DATE DATE,
   PROJECT_MANAGER varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE PARTICIPANT(
   PARTICIPANT_ID int,
   NAME varchar(50),
   PROJECT_ID int
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECT_TEAM(
   PROJECT_ID int,
   PARTICIPANT_ID int
);
```

Comment: Thanx for quick reply . Issue is I don't want to create table for participants. I want participants field in Project bean,& want to create table PROJECT_TEAM(PROJECT_ID int, PARTICIPANT_ID int); during inserting data in Project table &&& Project table should not have participants_id column. we can use  @Transient or something for that.

Comment: So the project table has a participant_id column? Can you post the DDL for this table?

Comment: When I insert Project Data like Project Title,Created date,Project Manager Participants Id. hibernate should be generating         CREATE TABLE PROJECT(
   PROJECT_ID int,
   PROJECT_TITLE varchar(50),
   CREATED_DATE DATE,
   PROJECT_MANAGER varchar(50)
);                                                                      CREATE TABLE PROJECT_TEAM(
   PROJECT_ID int,
   PARTICIPANT_ID int
);                                                                    Participants_id is Project Bean's Field (but not Column in Project Table)